# Wordpress: Notice: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to int on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a custom login page plugin, and the plugin works as expected. However, when I navigate to my home page, I get an error

> Notice: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to int in C:\MAMP\htdocs\wp-includes\general-template.php on line 1018

After I comment out parts of the code, I find out the `foreach` loop cause the problem. Need a solution.

```
// Set shortcode Tag
$login_shortcode = 'custom_login_form';


// Retrieve Login Page ID
$page_id = ! empty( $page_id ) ? $page_id : '';
$pages_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
);
$pages = get_pages( $pages_args );
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    if ( ( $page->post_title == 'Login' && strpos( $page->post_content, $login_shortcode ) ) && $page->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        $page_id = $page->ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: And just for curiosity, which is line 1018 out of the 18 lines you show us?

Comment: line 1018 is on wp-includes\general-template.php

Comment: Yeessss. But which of the lines you show to us above IS LINE 1018 :-(

Answer (score 3):

After I experimenting, I find out just by using another name for variable $page, the ERROR Notice gone:

Instead of using $page , I use $page_list

`$pages_args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' ); 
$page_list = get_pages( $pages_args );
// Wordpress: Notice: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to int on homepage
foreach ( $page_list as $individual_page ) {
    if ( ( $individual_page->post_title == 'Login' && strpos( $individual_page->post_content, $login_shortcode ) ) && $individual_page->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        $page_id = $individual_page->ID;
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks!  This was driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

`$page` is a global variable in WordPress, so if you define a `$page` variable in a template file, you are basically overriding the global variable, and weirdness will follow.

As a general rule always try to avoid using variables in template files which are too general like `$post`, because they might be global variables in WordPress, and templates are included in the global scope, so you might end up overriding something vital.